# mysqld on start and stop on Mac OS

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm on MacOS, and I used homebrew to install Mysql. However, when I want to start Mysql, I cannot use `mysql.server start`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8ykw.png

I can only use `mysqld` to start the server. But when I run `mysqld` I couldn't make it stop, I tried to close the window but that doesn't help either.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2gfq.png

I tried `Ctrl + C`, `Ctrl + X`, `Ctrl + Z` but no luck for me. Any solutions to stop mysqld?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, I cannot find a good way but there's a trick that may help you.

```
ps aux | grep mysql
# A list of process with mysql appeared, get the process id of the mysqld one then kill it by next  command
kill -9 <pid>
```

But I think someone should have better idea on this.

Comment: Thanks mate, it helps me to end this but I'd like a way to stop it on my current tab.